# IIS http authorization header raw?

Tags: http, authentication, iis

IIS automatically decodes the incoming authorization header and makes several headers available to the server script: AUTH_PASSWORD, AUTH_TYPE, AUTH_USER. But I need the raw header because I will pass it on. How do I get hold of it? Can I get it by asking for ALL_HTTP or ALL_RAW?

See: https: //msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Aw, it was no big deal. HTTP_AUTHORIZATION is still available, so you can choose whether you want it raw or decoded.

Never so bad that it isn't good for something: Now I have answered a question and you can give me points :)